# Change loaded file Django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to figure out Django. I had such a task: the user loads an xml file, and I have to process it and return certain data. I already have a desktop script for this using xlrd and openpyexel. The question is: how to immediately process the resulting file and immediately output the data to the user?

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import files

class DocumentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = files
        fields = ('File',)
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class files(models.Model):
    File = models.FileField(upload_to='files', null=True,)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from .forms import DocumentForm

def model_form_upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('portfolio:index')
    else:
        form = DocumentForm()
    return render(request, 'templates/upload/upload.html', {
        'form': form
    })
```

upload.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
  <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Upload</button>
  </form>

  <p><a href="{% url 'portfolio:index' %}">Return to home</a></p>
{% endblock %}
```